# CSS select several types under one id

Tags: css

I want to select all th and td under div.
Writing something like:

```
#div_id th,td {
   ...
}
```

is not good since it selects all the td-s.

I saw solution [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorgrouping) to write

```
#div_id th,#div_id td { 
   ... 
}
```

Is there other way, so I should not repeat the #div_id?

Thanks.

Comment: No; that's pretty much the only way. Unless you either assign `id` or `class` names to the individual `td` or `th` elements you want to target.

Comment: CSS is limited. That's why alternative syntaxes emerged. For instance, in SASS, you can write `#div_id`, and then in the next row `th, td`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure CSS wise, there is no better answer than your own. But you could look into [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or similar technologies, that would allow for things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code looks something like this:

```
<div id="div_id">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Header 1
            </th>
            <th>
                Header 2
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                row 1,
                <p>
                    cell 1
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                row 1,
                <p>
                    cell 2
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                row 2,
                <p>
                    cell 1
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                row 2, 
                <p>
                    cell 2
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You could apply a rule such as this:

```
#div_id tr > * {
    border: 1px dotted #CCC;
}​
```

Which selects the first element (and only the first element) inside of a `tr`, which is bound to only be a `th` or `td`.

Notice that if I had instead defined the rule as:

```
#div_id tr * {
    border: 1px dotted #CCC;
}​
```

The `p` tags would also have a dotted border.

However, it generally makes more sense to simply type the extra 8 characters as it's easier to understand what's you did later.

Comment: I assume by "first element" you mean all children. `:P`

Comment: Yes, all children but no grandchildren ect.